# Is it correct to dynamically change the proxy in this way in CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I try to dynamically modify the proxy by using this method:

```
console.log('before set proxy: '+Date());
casper.then(function(){
    phantom.setProxy('127.0.0.1',"1080","manual",'','');
})
this.then(function(){
    console.log('after set proxy: '+Date());
})
```

However, every time the `phantom.setProxy` spend 6 minutes:

```
before set proxy: Fri Dec 15 2017 09:56:41 GMT+0800 (CST)
[warning] [phantom] Loading resource failed with status=fail:         
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/7: done in 360210ms.
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 3/7: done in 360230ms.
after set proxy: Fri Dec 15 2017 10:02:31 GMT+0800 (CST)
```

What's wrong with this usage?
And in fact, the `phantom.setProxy('127.0.0.1',"1080","manual",'','')` has no effect, but the `phantom.setProxy('127.0.0.1',"1080","socks5",'','')` is effective.

Answer (score 1):

This maybe way too late to answers, but here We Go..

I didn't see any reference in PhantomJS website, how ever I see that in SlimerJS Doc Page >> https://docs.slimerjs.org/current/api/phantom.html#setproxy-host-port-proxytype-user-password

Proxy types:
 - “system”: Use system proxy settings
 - “auto”: Auto-detect proxy settings
 - “config-url”: Automatic proxy configuration URL
 - “socks” - “socks5”
 - “http” 
 - / null / undefined

There's the answer, "manual" is not one of possible option, you may use "http"